# How can I remove brackets from list, before putting that list into query?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have list `dati` that contains 3 column data. I have to insert into 8 tables 10 randomly chosen data from this list.

```
import random
dati=[("Lauris","24","lauris23@inbox.lv"),
              ("Ģirts","48","jutka@gmail.com"),
              ("Ivo","18","ikasd@yahoo.com"),
              ("Mikus","58","321es1@aol.net"),
              ("Tomass","34","jeg@outlook.net"),
              ("Zigis","34","zigis12@epasts.lv"),
              ("Lolita","14","lolita123@zoho.com"),
              ("Paula","87","paulalaura@mail.net"),
              ("Krists","37","37kristaps@inbox.lv"),
              ("Jurijs","62","jurij@rumail.ru"),
              ("Sandis","71","krap12@gmail.com"),
              ("Marta","29","marta29@inbox.lv")
                ]

for i in range(0,9):
    saraksts = random.sample(dati, 10)
    #query=(f"INSERT INTO Cilveki{i} VALUES{saraksts}"
    print(saraksts)
```

I want `saraksts` to be put in a string `query` without brackets. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert directly to string, there is a method to make our lives easy that is str.join

```
saraksts = list()
for i in range(0, 9):
    saraksts.append(''.join(dati[i]))

    # query=(f"INSERT INTO Cilveki{i} VALUES{saraksts}"
print(saraksts)
```

**NOTE** this generates a list of strings
so you will have all your data in a list which contains these names

In join you can give a seperator like '|'.join(data[i]) it will seperate your internal data inside array like this
Example:

Lauris|24|lauris23@inbox.lv

Now you can easily:

```
saraksts=random.sample(saraksts,7) //will generate list form 0 to 7
```